# How to determine two date is same day at local time in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, time, timezone, momentjs

Here are two date, `2015-11-10 09:00:00+08:00` and `2015-11-10 01:00:00+08:00` is same day in China. But they are different day in UTC.

So... How can I determine two UTC date is same day at different timezone in node.js?

---

Sorry for my ambiguous description and poor English.

I have two strings: start_time and end_time. And clint upload two other strings: timezone_str, utc_time_str.

I want to determine the client time is between start and end time.

e.g

- start_time: `2015-11-10 00:00:00`
- end_time: `2015-11-11 00:00:00`
- utc_time_str: `2015-11-10 02:00:00Z`
- timezone_str: `America/New_York`

except `client_time.isBetween(start_time, end_time) == false`.

Thanks to @Matt Johnson's answer, [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) can solve my problem.

```
client_time = moment(utc_time_str).tz(timezone_str);
start = moment.tz(start_time, timezone_str);
end = moment.tz(end, timezone_str);
client_time.isBetween(start, end) === false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way would be to use the [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) function in [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to retain the provided offset.  Then use the [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) function with the `'day'` argument, which tests for same year, month, and day.

```
var m1 = moment.parseZone("2015-11-10 09:00:00+08:00");
var m2 = moment.parseZone("2015-11-10 01:00:00+08:00");
if (m1.isSame(m2, 'day')) {
   // ...
}
```

With this approach, it does not matter what offset was given, nor does it matter what the time zone is on the computer where the code is running.   It simply compares the two dates as provided.

Answer (score 0):

calculate local "hours" like this

```
var d1 = new Date('2015-11-10 09:00:00+08:00')
var d2 = new Date('2015-11-10 01:00:00+08:00')

var h1 = d1.getHours() - d1.getTimezoneOffset() / 60
var h2 = d2.getHours() - d2.getTimezoneOffset() / 60

var date1 = d1.getDate() + (h1 >= 24? 1: 0)
var date2 = d2.getDate() + (h2 >= 24? 1: 0)
```

just compare date1 and date2

Comment: Sorry, but this will fail in several edge cases, as it's not accounting for precision of less than an hour, and `getTimezoneOffset` will reflect the time zone of the computer where the code is running, not the offset in the string passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution without MomentJS

1. If you have the timezone string of the user that is in accordance with the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), such as "America/New_York" — which you can get client side for example by doing: `const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;`
2. Then you could, for each date, create a new date with the timezone offset added to the original date, for example by doing `const dateInTimezone = new Date(new Date(myDate).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: timezone }))`;
3. And then reset the time values to exactly midnight of the same day by doing `dateInTimezone.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`;
4. Then you could compare the milliseconds since Epoch values (date we start counting UTC from) of the two dates to see whether they start in the same day or not: `const isSameDay = startOfDate1.valueOf() === startOfDate2.valueOf()`;

Ideally, your starting dates would always be in UTC, since both your server and client could be in all sorts of timezones. So before storing the data, convert the original date to its UTC version in milliseconds since Epoch, by doing `myOrignalDate.valueOf()` or `myOrignalDate.getTime()` — this way, you will ensure that timezone offsets added later will be true.

##### Example

```js
function isSameDayInTimezone(d1, d2, timezone) {
  const start_of_d1 = new Date(new Date(d1).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: timezone })).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf();
  const start_of_d2 = new Date(new Date(d2).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: timezone })).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf();

  return start_of_d1 === start_of_d2;
}

/* Initialize dates. Note that this will be the UTC time as milliseconds since 
Epoch of the date in whichever timezone it was originally captured in. If I 
capture it in my timezone, it would currently be UTC/GMT+3, hence if I were
to want to perform server-side actions taking into account my timezone, I'd 
also need to capture my tz database timezone string first, to then be able 
to, server-side, add my timezone offset to the captured UTC time. */
const date1 = new Date('August 31, 2022 20:16:00').valueOf();
const date2 = new Date('August 31, 2022 23:50:00').valueOf();
const date3 = new Date('August 31, 2022 00:00:00').valueOf();
const date4 = new Date('August 30, 2022 15:00:00').valueOf();

const fixedTimezone = "Europe/Tallinn";
const localTimezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

/* With fixed timezone */
console.log(isSameDayInTimezone(date1, date2, fixedTimezone));
console.log(isSameDayInTimezone(date1, date3, fixedTimezone));
console.log(isSameDayInTimezone(date1, date4, fixedTimezone));

/* With local timezone */
console.log(isSameDayInTimezone(date1, date2, localTimezone));
console.log(isSameDayInTimezone(date1, date3, localTimezone));
console.log(isSameDayInTimezone(date1, date4, localTimezone));
```

Voila, no MomentJS needed.